# How to restore Macbook Air to factory settings?

Tags: macos

*I am not a pro-Mac user (I am a Windows user)*

Here's what I did with my old Macbook Air,

1. Press COMMAND + R while booting and it went into the mode shown in the picture
2. Selected Macintosh HD to (hopefully) install Mac OS X again
3. Entered Apple ID credentials

However, upon logging in, a message box shows saying that the Apple ID has not been used with App Store then the install won't proceed.

What can be done to format the Macbook Air into factory settings.

Comment: Using a different Mac, log into the App store with your ID.

Comment: @xybrek: Have you tried Option-Command-R? You'll need to connect to WiFi at the boot screen. It should force the Mac to download the most recent recovery mode. 10.13 doesn't link to an Apple ID, so it may let you bypass logging in at install.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by creating a Mac OS X bootable USB which was way more straightforward than trying to re-install using existing image on the laptop. I have posted the solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that worked for me:

1. Download a Mac OS X image, a DMG file (High Sierra in my case)
2. Access a working Windows PC, download and install Transmac Software https://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm
3. Plug a suitable USB drive (16 GB in my case) and *format for Mac* using the Transmac software.
4. *Restore* the downloaded OS X image into the USB using the guide provided on the software website (the link on Step 2)
5. Plug the USB into the MacBook Air and boot from USB and waiter for 1 to 2 hours for the installation to finish, then log in my Apple ID (the same account I have tried on my OP)

Then everything worked fine. MacBook Air is fresh as new.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right there in your last line, "format the MacBook Air..." Or more correctly format the hard drive.

When you boot into Recovery Mode you should be given the option to launch Disk Utility. Do that, go into Disk Utility, select the Macintosh HD volume/partition and format it.

Once there is *nothing* on the internal drive it should allow you to install macOS and there should be no conflict with the credentials previously used.

If you have not established an AppleID and logged into the App Store before you may need to do this once. It will likely want a payment method (credit card) but downloading and installing macOS is free. You should be able to do this in iTunes on your MacBook Air before you do the whole reformat then reinstall routine.